# Changin images on conditions

Tags: image, react-native

I want to change my source of image on certain conditions. I tried this

**MY IMPORTS**

```
import img1 from '../assets/1.png'
import img2 from '../assets/7.png'
```

**My code**

```
<Image {...(name === 'img1') ? source = { require(img1) } : source = { require(img2) }} style={styles.img} />
```

but the change doesn't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace you code as below,

```
<Image style={styles.img} source={name === 'img1' ? require("../assets/1.png") : require("../assets/7.png")} />
```

Hope this help you. Feel free for doubts.